# How to know removed DOM element properties

Tags: javascript

I have an element, that yet added to the page and before that I need to know his properties, for example padding. I try to use adapter

```
getStyle: function (oElm, strCssRule)
```

but can't to receive that css rule without element on the page. How I can do that without element in the document?

I need properties on the first alert : http://jsfiddle.net/hWpeF/

Comment: `myelement.style.padding` ? http://jsfiddle.net/hBbyY/2/

Comment: give undefined coz the element not on the page

Comment: not on page than where ?????? Fiddle it out !!!!!

Comment: rps, http://jsfiddle.net/hBbyY/2/

Comment: rajesh kakawat, updated

Comment: give undefined to what? what is undefined? div? show the element in code

Comment: A very simple ans to your question is you cannot access properties of element that has not being attached to `DOM`.I dont know what are you trying to say with `I have an element, that yet added to the page and before`

Comment: Your Fiddle works for me (alerts whatever padding-value I set). So what's the problem?

Comment: sorry, mistake - wrong fiddle - now actual, thanks

Comment: captain, for example can I receive props from css styles, mb there are some tricks?

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: @user2560165 why not you can. In Jquery like `$("id").css("attr")` or may be using plain javascript `document.getElementById("id").style.attr`

Comment: captain, in my code I give to the element css class, but cant receive padding property without adding element to the page, but I need it coz I try fit the DIV element to the page

Comment: @user2560165 can you paste some of your code here ? Please.

Comment: captain, in the fiddle the same situation, thanks

Comment: ok, the best way - addElement with display: none and we can get style props, then when we need we can set display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

the best way - addElement with display: none and we can get style props, then when we need we can set display: inline-block